# !v command UNIX - relation to Vi or vim

Tags: command-line, gvim, unix

Whenever I type `!v` command in the UNIX terminal, in a particular directory, my vim editor opens with the file "hello.txt" which I have never created in that same directory or anywhere.

What is the significance of `!v` command in UNIX and how is it related to Vi or vim?
I cannot get anything about this command on the lists of vim commands.
Please help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a shell mechanism rather than a vi or vim mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, `!` is used for [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html). You can inspect the shell history by running the command `history`.

So when typing `!v` your shell (I assume bash), will execute the last command that started with `v`, in your case apparently that was `vim hello.txt` and that's what is happening here.

Personally, I found that behaviour too annoying, so that I have disabled this in bash using `set +H` in my `.bashrc` file. But sometimes, this can be quite useful, if you need to re-execute a previous command.

For more information, please read the manual of your shell.

Note: this is the wrong forum, to ask Unix questions.

Comment: Thanks, understood, and even checked and verified. Apologies, I wasn't able to differentiate whether to ask in UNIX or Vim because this was always happening related to vim editor, I thought its related to vim. Now I got how history works, I always thought it is related only by "!the_command_number".